# Forcing mvn to latest spring release for drools-camel

Tags: spring, tomcat, maven, apache-camel, drools

I've a project that uses Apache Camel (2.10-SNAPSHOT) and Spring (3.0.7.RELEASE) with Tomcat (7.0.26).

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>3.0.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <camel.version>2.10-SNAPSHOT</camel.version>
</properties>
```

Now I want to use the drools-camel component. So added the following in my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-camel</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I can build my project but I get a runtime exception.

```
[          http-bio-8080-exec-7] ContextLoader                  ERROR Context initialization failed
306 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.add(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)Lorg/springframework/beans/MutablePropertyValues;
307         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
308         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
309         at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
310         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
311         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
312         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
313         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
314         at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
315         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
316         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
317         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
318         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
319         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
320         at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)[spring-2.5.6.jar:2.5.6]
321         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
322         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
323         at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
324         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
325         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
326         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
327         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
328         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
329         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
330         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_29]
331         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_29]
332         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_29]
333         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_29]
334         at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
335         at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)[:1.6.0_29]
336         at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)[:1.6.0_29]
337         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
338         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
339         at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
340         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)[servlet-api.jar:]
341         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[servlet-api.jar:]
342         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
343         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
344         at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
345         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
346         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
347         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
348         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
349         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
350         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
351         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
352         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
353         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
354         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
355         at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
356         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
357         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
358         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_29]
359         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_29]
360         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_29]
```

I think the error is related to using the **wrong version (spring-2.5.6) of Spring jars (see     `[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile`
in the mvn dependency output below.**. 
The the maven dependency output shows the cause to be drools. **Is there is way to force drools-camel component to use the version of spring defined in pom.xml ?**

I'm using maven (**mvn -version Apache Maven 3.0.3** (r1075438; 2011-02-28 12:31:09-0500))

```
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-core:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-spring:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-stream:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-cxf-transport:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-common-utilities:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-api:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.ws.rs:jsr311-api:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-xml:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-common:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xml-resolver:xml-resolver:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- asm:asm:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-simple:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-ws-addr:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-blueprint:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-xml:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.camel:camel-core-osgi:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.aries.blueprint:org.apache.aries.blueprint:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.aries:org.apache.aries.util:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.aries.testsupport:org.apache.aries.testsupport.unit:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.aries.proxy:org.apache.aries.proxy.api:jar:0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-bindings-soap:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.apache.cxf:cxf-tools-common:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-http:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_2.5_spec:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-twitter:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-core:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.twitter4j:twitter4j-stream:jar:2.2.5:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-xstream:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- xmlpull:xmlpull:jar:1.1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c:compile
[INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.woodstox:woodstox-core-asl:jar:4.1.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0-2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-csv:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.servicemix.bundles:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-csv:jar:1.0-r706899_3:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-jackson:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.0.7.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.camel:camel-test:jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.16:compile
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.drools:drools-camel:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.drools:knowledge-api:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.drools:drools-core:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.mvel:mvel2:jar:2.1.0.drools4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.antlr:antlr-runtime:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.antlr:antlr:jar:3.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.antlr:stringtemplate:jar:3.2.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:3.5.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.jbpm:jbpm-flow-builder:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.jbpm:jbpm-flow:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO]    +- org.drools:drools-spring:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.drools:drools-decisiontables:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     +- org.drools:drools-templates:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |     \- net.sourceforge.jexcelapi:jxl:jar:2.6.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.drools:drools-grid-impl:jar:5.3.0.Final:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.mina:mina-core:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.hazelcast:hazelcast:jar:1.8.5:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.hibernate:ejb3-persistence:jar:1.0.2.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:jar:3.4.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:3.3.2.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javax.persistence:persistence-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.0.GA:compile
[INFO]    |  \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.camel:camel-jaxb:jar:2.4.0:compile
[INFO]    |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging-api:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.1.12:compile
**[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring:jar:2.5.6:compile**
[INFO]    \- org.apache.cxf:cxf-bundle-jaxrs:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.ws.xmlschema:xmlschema-core:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-stax-api_1.0_spec:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-annotation_1.0_spec:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.neethi:neethi:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO]       +- wsdl4j:wsdl4j:jar:1.6.2:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-activation_1.1_spec:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-javamail_1.4_spec:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-continuation:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-http:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-io:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-util:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       +- org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-security:jar:7.4.2.v20110526:compile
[INFO]       \- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec:jar:1.0:compile
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add desired spring version as separate dependency and exclude that one, that comes with drools:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-camel</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: The output of <code>mvn dependency:tree</code> doesn't show the spring-2.5.6 dependency anymore. However, I'm still get the same runtime exception. Any ideas ?

Comment: You may look at resolved libs in WAR, ensure that there are no duplication of spring libs any more, than find JAR, causes this error, see it's version in manifest or pom file, than look at sources of this version of lib to ensure it has proper method defined.

Comment: This error is fixed but I'm getting another one that may or may not be related. Thanks again !

Comment: this is the error i'm getting. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762861/drools-and-camel-failed-to-load-type-converters-cannot-find-any-type-converter