# Drools and Camel : Failed to load type converters Cannot find any type converter classes [org.drools.camel.component]

Tags: spring, tomcat, apache-camel, drools

Can someone help me with the following exception. I'm using Apache Camel (2.10-SNAPSHOT) and Spring (3.0.7.RELEASE) with Tomcat (7.0.26).

My Drools dependency in my pom.xml is

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-camel</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.0.Final</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Exception on Tomcat log is -

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.TypeConverterLoaderException: Failed to load type converters because of: Cannot find any type converter classes from the following packages: [org.drools.camel.component]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1221)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getTypeConverter(DefaultCamelContext.java:1052)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getTypeConverterRegistry(DefaultCamelContext.java:1067)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.forceLazyInitialization(DefaultCamelContext.java:2064)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:1521)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:1431)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.doStart(SpringCamelContext.java:179)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:60)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:1399)[camel-core-2.10-20120318.032230-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.maybeStart(SpringCamelContext.java:228)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext.onApplicationEvent(SpringCamelContext.java:118)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.apache.camel.spring.CamelContextFactoryBean.onApplicationEvent(CamelContextFactoryBean.java:243)[camel-spring-2.10-20120318.032739-65.jar:2.10-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:303)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:911)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)[spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)[spring-web-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:536)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1467)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)[:1.6.0_29]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)[:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:836)[:1.6.0_29]
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:761)[:1.6.0_29]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1436)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.deploy(ManagerServlet.java:673)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doPut(ManagerServlet.java:431)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)[servlet-api.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)[servlet-api.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)[catalina.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)[tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.26]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)[:1.6.0_29]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)[:1.6.0_29]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is being discussed and answered at the Camel mailing list
http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/org-apache-camel-RuntimeCamelException-org-apache-camel-TypeConverterLoaderException-Failed-to-load--td5575757.html

Its a bug in drools-camel, which has invalid meta data in the JAR